# Embedded linux SDK for WebRTC

Tags: video-streaming, embedded-linux, webrtc

Is there any Embedded Linux SDK for the WebRTC API in existence?  Or any one still in development?

The goal would be to make a camera running embedded Linux that can directly use WebRTC to communicate with Web Browsers using p2p and not have to utilize some middle Media Server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recall there is already people doing this. There is a webrtc native api and can be used. 
This is a know how to use it 
https://webrtc.org/native-code/
And when you compile it you could see the peerconnection 
There is additional work to be done found in 
http://sourcey.com/webrtc-native-to-browser-video-streaming-example/

The problem is as I recall is how you use the ninja build tools in your respective board. If you are successful you could use p2p directly to webclient.

It is probably the closest you could get to the webrtc api in embeddedd linux